# How to say "I want; I don't want" without a verb?

Tags: grammar

I know how to say "I want" using たい after a verb, but how a say just "I want, I don't want" without a verb? Using just たい
Or たいくない? And in the past?

Answer (score 5):

You can say it using the word ほしい. For example:

> 新{あたら}しい車{くるま}がほしい。
>   I want a new car.

ほしい conjugates the same way as a normal i-adjective:

> ほしかった
>   ほしくない
>   ほしくなかった

BTW, I don't know if it was just a typo but it should be たくない not たいくない for the negative form.

Answer (score 0):

〜が欲しい - I want ...
〜が欲しくない - I don't want ...
〜が欲しかった - I wanted ...
〜が欲しくなかった - I didn't want ...

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide an explanation and some examples.